# Removing all the characters between two specific tags (java regex)

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to remove html content and the tags

```
<DATE> html content </DATE>
```

These are the different versions of the code I have tried, none of them worked:

```
content = content.replaceAll("<DATE>(?s:)</DATE>", "");
content = content.replaceAll("<DATE>(?:.|\n)</DATE>", "");
content = content.replaceAll("<DATE>" + Pattern.DOTALL + "</DATE>", "");
content = content.replaceAll("<DATE>(.*?)</DATE>", "");
```

Any suggestions?

Complete Code:

```
Path corpusPath = Paths.get(path + file);
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(corpusPath), charset);
content = content.replaceAll("<HEADLINE>", "<DOCHDR>");
content = content.replaceAll("</HEADLINE>", "</DOCHDR>");
content = content.replaceAll("<DATE>(.*?)</DATE>", "");
Path destPath = Paths.get(path + "Parsed\\" +file);
Files.write(destPath, content.getBytes(charset));
```

Comment: Can you share the complete code? The last one should work.

Comment: `Pattern.DOTALL` is not a pattern that you can put in the middle of a regex.  It's a flag that is passed when matching, to change the behavior of the pattern matcher.  It's actually an `int`, so if you try to concatenate it to a string you'll get an unwanted integer in the pattern (the pattern will be `"<DATE>32</DATE>"` which is definitely wrong).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the below regex to remove `<DATE>` tag along with it's content,

```
content = content.replaceAll("(?s)<DATE>.*?</DATE>", "");
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?s)` DOTALL Modifier enables DOTALL mode. It make dot to match even newline characters also.
- `<DATE>` Matches the starting `<DATE>` tag.
- `.*?` Matches any character upto the next `</DATE>` string. `?` after `*` tells the regex engine to does a shortest match.
- Finally the matched characters are replaced with null string.

Comment: No need to escape the forward slash.

Comment: Yes it works without escaping the slash. both versions works. Thank you so much. Can you explain the reason? What is the one you put before <DATE> ?

Comment: More details if needed: `(?s)` enables the DOTALL mode. From [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL): *"In dotall mode, the expression `.` matches any character, including a line terminator. By default this expression does not match line terminators."*.

Comment: Nice answer. Users only have to see if they had a clear tag. For example my tag was with a complement <Polygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">, so I had to edit it on the regex.