# Remove text between xml tags and still keep tags

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm trying to remove text between xml tags, while still keeping the tags, using Groovy. The closest answer I've been able to find was here:

[Removing all the characters between two specific tags (java regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784707/removing-all-the-characters-between-two-specific-tags-java-regex)

But that removes the tags as well. A workaround would be to use:

```
    String content = "<DATE> html content </DATE>"
    content = content.replaceAll("(?s)<DATE>.*?</DATE>", "<DATE></DATE>")
```

That gets the job done, but I want to know if there's a cleaner way of removing only the text and keeping the tags?

Answer (score 1):

Another method, it to go through every node in the tree, and set it's value to just be the child nodes (which will remove the strings)...  like so:

```
def x = '''
  <root>
    <a>I'm text</a>
    <b>
      So am I
      <c woo="yay">And me!</c>
      last one
    </b>
    Some more text
  </root>'''

import groovy.xml.*

def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(x)

xml.'**'.each { node ->
    if (node instanceof Node) {
        node.value = node.children().findAll { it instanceof Node }
    }
}

println XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

The output of which will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
  <a/>
  <b>
    <c woo="yay"/>
  </b>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

If assume that structure of your xml is always the same then

```
content = new XmlParser().parseText("<DATE> html content </DATE>")
content.setValue("")
return XmlUtil.serialize(content)
```

But frankly if tag name never changes why not just return constant string?

```
content = "<DATE></DATE>"
```